# Авто-выдача ролей при входе на сервер

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, discord-api

Хочу реализовать следующее:

При входе на сервер нового участника, ему автоматически должна выдаваться роль. Звучит просто.

Код:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=config.autoRoleId)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print("{} joined to channel! Role: {}".format(member, role.id))
```

Но мне возвращает ошибку:

```
$ main.py 
Successful connected to discord server! # Коннектимся к серверам
Bot is ready # Бот работает
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ReiVanSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ReiVanSTR\Python code\ReiB1\main.py", line 23, in on_member_join
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\ReiVanSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason) # Пробовал и так, возвращает так же Missing Permissions
  File "C:\Users\ReiVanSTR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Позже из доков прочитал, что для этого нужны права **manage_roles**

```
await add_roles(*roles, reason=None, atomic=True)
    This function is a coroutine.
    Gives the member a number of Roles.
    You must have the manage_roles permission to use this.
```

Выдавать роли @everyone доступ к редактированию это самоубийство, даже если выдать доступ, то любая новая роль будет стоять выше @everyone, а доступ **manage_roles** разрешает редактирование только нижестоящих ролей

**Полный код**

```
import config
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.prefix)

@client.event # Connecting to discord server
async def on_connect():
    print("Successful connected to discord server!")
@client.event
async def on_ready(): # When bot is ready
    print("Bot is ready")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game("Python"))
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=config.autoRoleId)
    await member.add_roles(role)
    print("{} joined to channel! Role: {}".format(member, role.id))

client.run(config.token)
```

Буду рад любому ответу!

Comment: в настройках ролей попробуй бота переместить выше всех ролей

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Роль бота находится выше выдаваемых ролей

Answer (score 1):

## **UPD:** Проблема решена!

При подключении бота я выдал ему права **администратора**, после выбора этой роли, нижестоящие роли стали недоступны, т.к. предполагается, что они уже включены в роль **Администратор**. Скриншоты ниже:

[image: Give perm]

### Решение:

Перейти в настройки сервера, в настройках ролей выбрать роль бота и выдать доступ к **"Управлять ролями"** (**manage_roles**)

Не знаю, можно ли списать это на недоработку самого API? С другой стороны, дискорд настоятельно **НЕ**рекомендует выдавать роль администратора.

### Вывод:

Выдавать боту только те права, которые ему нужны для корректной работы. Это не только обезопасит Ваш сервер, но и как показывает практика не будет вызывать подобных проблем.